# Determining tangent to a curve $f(x,y)=constant$ at a given point $(x=a,y=b)$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, tangent-line

I'll have to figure out the tangent of a curve given by the expression $f(x,y)=constant$ and the angle $\theta$ it makes at a given point $(x=a,y=b)$. What I am getting is that the tan of the angle is being reproduced by

$$\tan(\theta)=-\frac{\partial_x f}{\partial_y f}\Bigg |_{(a,b)}$$

however, I don't really understand why that must be true. Can someone kindly prove this result or explain how to go about getting a general expression for the tangent of the given curve at a given point?

Comment: Try it with a circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. The slope of the normal at $(a,b)$ on the circle  is given by $\displaystyle \frac{\partial_y f}{\partial_x f}\Bigg |_{(a,b)}$ , it is along the radius from the center. The tangent is perpendicular to the normal. If $s$ is the slope of a vector then the perpendicular to it has slope $\frac{-1}{s}$. With the slope and one point you can construct the equation of the tangent line. A textbook should provide a formal proof.

Comment: @arthur Any reference to books will also be helpful

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Equations

Comment: @arthur Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $L:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:f(x,y)=K\}$. If $g:(-1,1)\to L$ is a (local) regular parametrization of $L$ with $g(0)=(a,b)$ then a tangent vector at $(a,b)$ in $\operatorname{img}(g)$ is given by $g'(0)$. Now observe that $f\circ g=K$, therefore

$$
\partial (f\circ g)(0)=\partial f(g(0))g'(0)=\nabla f(a,b)\cdot g'(0)=0
$$

so any tangent vector at $(a,b)$ in $\operatorname{img}(g)$ is orthogonal to $\nabla f(a,b)$. From here you can easily find a normalized tangent vector at $(a,b)$ just rotating $v:=\frac{\nabla f(a,b)}{\|\nabla f(a,b)\|}$ 90 degrees clockwise, from where compute your angle $\theta $.